# MySQL statement that combines a sub-query and a JOIN is not working

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

```
SELECT i.id AS id, i.modify_date as modify_date, s.subscription as subscriptionid, p.paid/i.total AS paidratio 
    FROM invoices i,
         (SELECT p.invoice, sum(amount) AS paid FROM payments p GROUP BY p.invoice) p
        LEFT JOIN sub_to_inv s 
            ON i.id=s.invoice
    WHERE p.invoice=i.id 
        AND i.corporation='3' 
        AND i.payer=1
```

The error I get is "unknown column on i.id" which is total bogus - invoices (i) has an id row for sure. They all do.

The purpose of the sub=query is to find out how much of the invoice has been paid. For an invoice that has a "total" column of 1000.00, for example, could have 2 or 3 split payments. What I ultimately wnat to do here is list all the unpaid invoices or partially invoices first. But before I even get to the ORDER BY stage, I need to figure out this error.

Comment: Which i.id is it complaining about?  Could it be confused about "i.id AS id"?  Maybe try changing that alias to something else and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
SELECT i.id AS id, i.modify_date as modify_date, s.subscription as subscriptionid, p.paid/i.total AS paidratio 
    FROM invoices i
        LEFT JOIN
          (SELECT p.invoice, sum(amount) AS paid FROM payments p GROUP BY p.invoice) p
          ON p.invoice=i.id 
        LEFT JOIN sub_to_inv s 
            ON i.id=s.invoice
    WHERE  i.corporation='3' 
        AND i.payer=1
```

Comment: Didn't do the exadt thing, but moved the position of the JOIN statement to after "FROM invoices i" and it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JOIN` syntax for all joins.  Don't mix `JOIN` syntax with the comma-style SQL-89 syntax.

```
SELECT ...
FROM invoices i
  INNER JOIN (SELECT...) p
    ON p.invoice=i.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sub_to_inv s 
    ON i.id=s.invoice
WHERE 
    AND i.corporation='3' 
    AND i.payer=1
```

Explanation:  `JOIN` has higher precedence than comma-joins.  So `p JOIN s` is evaluated before the query evaluates the join to `i`.  Therefore, in the clause `ON i.id=s.invoice`, the `i` table is not yet known and is an invalid reference.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html, in the doc following "Join Processing Changes in MySQL 5.0.12".

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be running into issues because of the order of your table joins in your SQL. Have you tried using an inner join. Perhaps try:

```
SELECT 
  i.id AS id, 
  i.modify_date as modify_date, 
  s.subscription as subscriptionid, 
  p.paid/i.total AS paidratio 
FROM
  invoices i
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 
    p.invoice,
    sum(amount) AS paid
  FROM
    payments p
  GROUP BY
    p.invoice) p
ON
  p.invoice=i.id
LEFT JOIN
  sub_to_inv s
ON
  i.id=s.invoice
WHERE
  i.corporation='3' AND i.payer=1
```

Comment: Remove the comma after `invoices i` :-)